# Select2- How to access property value of remote data - Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 to fetch data via ajax from the url `https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/`. The request is able to return some json data, however, mapping the indexes to the select options returns a console warning message " Cannot read properties of undefined".

My intention is to get the value of the `matching_full_name` index from the json object.

```js
$('.select2-cities').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        search: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },

    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            text: item._embedded['city:search-results'].matching_full_name,
            id: item._embedded['city:search-results'].matching_full_name,
          }
        })
      };
    },

    cache: true
  },
  placeholder: 'Search for a city',
  minimumInputLength: 1,
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="w-100"> City</label>
        <select class="select2-cities form-control">

        </select>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes the data returned is:

```
data [array]
       _embedded
           city:search_results
```

when it's actually

```
data
    _embedded
           city:search_results [array]
```

so looping `$.map(data, (item) =>` gives `item` as the `_embedded` property as that's the first property of data.  As such, there's no `_embedded` property of `_embedded` and you get your error.

Instead, you need to loop the results array:

```
results: $.map(data._embedded['city:search-results'], function(item) {
```

Updated snippet

```js
$('.select2-cities').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        search: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },

    processResults: function(data) {
      //console.log(data)
      return {
        results: $.map(data._embedded['city:search-results'], function(item) {
          //console.log(item)
          return {
            text: item.matching_full_name,
            id: item.matching_full_name,
          }
        })
      };
    },

    cache: true
  },
  placeholder: 'Search for a city',
  minimumInputLength: 1,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="w-100"> City</label>
      <select class="select2-cities form-control">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```